# How to run a program every k seconds

Tags: automation

Suppose that I want to write a program that does something automatically over a period of time. More concretely, suppose I want something to run every k seconds.

What is the normal practice for doing this? I'm not looking for a language-specific answer, but rather a general idea of how a developer runs a process (whether it be a binary or some other computational task) automatically every k seconds.

Comment: To be able to answer this, we need to know what platform the process will be running on. Linux, Windows, OSX, etc. Also, this is probably a duplicate of several other posts.

Comment: Also, it depends on how big the k seconds are. If it is small (less than a minute, or minute granularity is needed) that will require a whole different solution than something that runs with the granularity of minutes, hours, or days.  

You will get better results, if you update the question to make it more specific.

For example, ask "how do I run a process to check if a file changed periodically", or "how do I get the latest stock info every 5 minutes"

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The programmer approach:-

When there is a particular program or script that needs to be executed every k seconds, programmers generally uses CRON jobs functionality. Here's the definition from google.

*The software utility **Cron** is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems. People who set up and maintain software environments use cron to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to run periodically at fixed times, dates, or intervals.*

But when there is piece of code. Let's say a function in javascript program, programmers run it in every k seconds like this.

```
function hello()
{
     document.write("Hello World<br>");
}
setInterval(hello, 1000); //1000 is time in milliseconds. 'hello' function will be called every 1000 milliseconds.
```

Here's a tutorial to do it in php http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Hopes it helps you !!!